# Understanding the application of Markov's inequality in a probability journal paper

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

> I am trying to understand why the inequality (1) shown below holds. This is above (5.3) in page 28 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.08564.pdf). The explanation given in the paper is that it follows from the Markov's inequality, and I don't understand how.

Let $S$ be an event, $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$ be a sigma algebra, $G_n^\star$ be a random graph. The precise definitions of $S,\mathcal{F}_{i-1}, G_n^\star$ are not needed for my question. In the paragraph above the inequality I am considering, it is mentioned that $\mathbb{P}(S\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1})\geq 1-\varepsilon^2$. Then the paper considers the following set:
$$\mathcal{G} = \{G:\mathbb{P}(S\mid G_n^\star = G)\geq 1-\varepsilon\}$$

> Then the paper says that by using the Markov's inequality, the following inequality holds (I am trying to understand why this is true): $$\mathbb{P}(G_n^\star\in \mathcal{G}\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1})\geq 1-\varepsilon \tag{1}$$

My attempt at understanding this: I am thinking that:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(G_n^\star\in \mathcal{G}\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}) &= \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{P}(S\mid G_n^\star)\geq 1-\varepsilon\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}) \\
&\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(S\mid G_n^\star)\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}]}{(1-\varepsilon)} \tag{2}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(S\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1})}{(1-\varepsilon)}
\end{align}
where the inequality (2) follow from the Markov's inequality. So I am getting an upper bound for $\mathbb{P}(G_n^\star\in \mathcal{G}\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1})$ using the Markov's inequality and not a lower bound as shown in (1). It'd be great to know what is wrong in my argument and/or why the inequality (1) is true. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to go to the compliment (multiple times). When you want to show a lower bound, you can instead show an upper bound (for example by the Markov inequality) for the complement.

More precisely:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(G_n^*\not\in \mathcal G\vert \mathcal F_{i-1}) &= \mathbb P(\mathbb P (S\vert G_n^*) < 1 - \epsilon)\vert \mathcal F_{i-1})\\
&=\mathbb P(\mathbb P(S^c\vert G_n^*) \geq \epsilon\vert \mathcal F_{i-1})\\
&\leq \dfrac{\mathbb E[\mathbb P(S^c\vert G_n^*)\vert \mathcal F_{i-1}]}{\epsilon}\\
&= \dfrac{\mathbb P(S^c\vert \mathcal F_{i-1})}{\epsilon} \leq \dfrac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon} = \epsilon,
\end{align*}
so that
$$
\mathbb P(G_n^*\in\mathcal G\vert\mathcal F_{i-1}) \geq 1 - \epsilon.
$$